# How to access SQL Server database in WPF via passing database name

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, ado.net

I am using Ado.Net Connectivity Framework in my WPF application.

There is kind of a form in my `MainWindow.xaml` file. This form has two fields one is asking for database name and second is for PC Name.

**Questions:**

1. I want to pass these values to App.config File in my WPF application. How to pass these values?
2. Secondly *I have to make* my database centralized and my application launched from different computers have to access this centralized database?
3. The way I am making this to access centralized database via these above defined fields is right way or is this is not a way to achieve required goal?

[image]

Comment: If you break down the components in connectionstring to AppSetting and then you can read and write. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14744/Read-Write-App-Config-File-with-NET-2-0  Not sure how writing to the local app.config is going to address #3?

Comment: I'm a little confused here.  If the database is supposed to be centralized (item 2), why are you asking the user for a database name?   All uses I know of for "central" means there is exactly one.  Also, why do you ask the user for their PC name?  Wouldn't a better plan be to just simply pull that from the machine itself?

Comment: @ChrisLively thank you for your response : ) ... actually it's my first time to this kind of task can you please tell me that what's a better way to make all application to work for a single database by passing required values? is my this query clear to you. :)

Comment: So, you have a database, located in a centralized location, and you want each of your client applications to access it?

Comment: @paqogomez yes exactly this is what i want ...

Comment: Why then is the name of the client pc important?  You can have a query string like `<add name="myserverdb" connectionString=".......data source=myServer;..... />`  This connection string can be deployed with the app.config of your application to each client.

Comment: Thank you for reply! As application is on different machines so @paqogomez is it not necessary to give machine address on which application is running? :)

Comment: A connection string is just a way to point your application to a data source, wherever that data source may be.  It does not need to know where it is (your local pc) just where it is going (your server).  Does that help?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37898/discussion-between-tameen-malik-and-paqogomez)

Comment: Your WPF application is not the source of the data.  The centralized database is the source of the data.  This form should not even be in your application.

Comment: Thank you @Blam so what's a better way? :)

Comment: Create a proper connectionstring when you build the application.  If it is a centralized database then all clients should have the same connection string.  There are lots of examples on msdn.

Comment: Sir @Blam ! can you please provide me few example-links here, i searched for this but didn't find a good one. As you have more experience then me so sir can you please provide me reference of a good one. i will be grateful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We found an answer based on a [good sized chat discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37898/discussion-between-tameen-malik-and-paqogomez).

His solution will probably require 1 of 2 things.

0. Host a [WCF service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx) that performs [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operations on his database.
1. Use a service like [No IP](http://noip.com) to create a public location to his local machine, open ports for his database, and run the application with a direct connection.  (he is aware of the limitations/security problems this creates)